# How can i run different functions depending on the value of a variable?

Tags: c++, function, variables

How do I run a function depending on a variables value without using tons of `if` or `switch` statements?

at the moment I'm repeating a lot of code and doing something like this

The 2 variables represent data i am reading from a socket.
i need to do something different depending on the data i recieve

```
//Class1.h
class Class1 {
public:
    Class1();
    virtual ~Class1();

    unsigned char mode = 0x00;
    unsigned char type = 0x00;

    Interface* o;//in this case I’m creating an object not running a function
};

//Class1.cpp

#include "Class1.h"

Class1::Class1(){

    switch(mode){
    case 0x00:
        switch(type){
        case 0x00:
            o = new Class2();
            break;
        case 0x01:
            o = new Class3();
            break;
        case 0x02:
            o = new Class4();
            break;
        }
        //case 0x03
        //case 0x04
        //...
        break;
    //case 0x01
    //case 0x02
    //...
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: a) Is there a connection between the numbers and the classes? If it some arbitrary order, the computer has to know somehow. b) Why it is too much to make an if for each class, but the classes aren´t too much? With so many classes, overthink your design.

Comment: I am reading data from a socket and the 2 variables is some data im reading, i need it to do different things depending on the data it recieves

Comment: you could use some kind of map to instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd split the instance creation into its own factory class, something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface() = 0;
};
Interface::~Interface() {}

class InterfaceFactory
{
public:
    typedef Interface* (*InterfaceCreator)();
    void registerInterface(unsigned char mode , unsigned char type, InterfaceCreator creator )
    {
        int16_t key = getKey(mode, type);
        table[key] = creator;
    }
    Interface* createInterface(unsigned char mode, unsigned char type) const
    {
        int16_t key = getKey(mode, type);
        Interface* iface = nullptr;
        std::map<int16_t, InterfaceCreator>::const_iterator cit = table.find(key);
        if (cit != table.end())
            iface = (*(cit->second))();
        return iface;
    }
private:
    int16_t getKey(unsigned char mode, unsigned char type) const
    {
        int16_t key = mode;
        key <<= 8;
        key += type;
        return key;
    }
    std::map<int16_t, InterfaceCreator> table;
};

//StreamProcessor.h
class StreamProcessor {
public:
    StreamProcessor(const InterfaceFactory& fact)
        : factory(fact)
    {}
    virtual ~StreamProcessor();
    bool initHandler(unsigned char mode = 0x00, unsigned char type = 0x00);
private:
    const InterfaceFactory& factory;
    Interface* o;//in this case I’m creating an object not running a function
};

//StreamProcessor.cpp

//#include "StreamProcessor.h"

bool StreamProcessor::initHandler(unsigned char mode , unsigned char type )
{
    o = factory.createInterface(mode, type);
    return o != 0;

}

class Class2 : public Interface
{
public:
    static Interface* create()
    {
        return new Class2;
    }
};
class Class3 : public Interface
{
public:
    static Interface* create()
    {
        return new Class3;
    }
};

int main()
{
    InterfaceFactory factory;
    factory.registerInterface(0x00, 0x00, &Class2::create);
    factory.registerInterface(0x00, 0x01, &Class3::create);
    StreamProcessor sp(factory);
    if (!sp.initHandler(0x00, 0x01))
    {
        throw "Unknown interface type";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no really clean solution, but if you really have classes named "Class%d", you can exploit the preprocessor to make your code somewhat shorter by using your variable's values as part of class names.

I'm not too fond of this, but I can't think of too many alternatives.

```
#define HANDLE_HUNDREDS_OF_CASES(x) case x: o = new Class##x(); break;

int type=1;
switch(type) {
HANDLE_HUNDREDS_OF_CASES(0); //< Will construct a new Class0 if type==0
HANDLE_HUNDREDS_OF_CASES(1); //< Will construct a new Class1 if type==1
HANDLE_HUNDREDS_OF_CASES(2); // Etc ...
HANDLE_HUNDREDS_OF_CASES(5);
HANDLE_HUNDREDS_OF_CASES(100);

default:
     break;
}
```

If you just want to call functions and not constructors, you can create an array of function pointers and use your variable as an index into that array.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use vector save all class object you have, and get object by the data you recieved.

```
  class Base{
      virtual void doSomeThing();
  }
  class A : public Base{
      virtual void doSomeThing() {
      }
  }

  class B : public Base{
      virtual void doSomeThing() {
      }
  }

  class Handler {
       vector<Base *> vet;
       void init() {
           vet.push_back(new A());
           vet.push_back(new B());
       }

       void handle(int code) {
           Base * obj = vet.get(code);
           obj->doSomeThing();
       }
  }
```

Comment: Assuming there are dozens or hundreds of possible classes, that's a lot of memory wasted. If there are just 2-3 classes, then you'd just use a switch or if regardless.

Comment: A few hundred pointers isn't a big deal.  Also, it's not like you magically save memory by using a switch statement, you just move the memory burden from a data structure to the executable code.  As for allocating the objects themselves, the optimizer will probably make some changes if it can, especially if the objects don't have any members except their virtual table (a good optimizer will probably turn this into a vector of function pointers).